# Azure Logic App - read big file (200mb+) from sharepoint via "Get File Contetnt"

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

Have error with reading file about about **200mb** in **Logic App** using sharepoint connector **Get File Contetnt**.

When run pipeline facing on **Get file content** face error:

> **BadRequest
> Http request failed as there is an error: 'Cannot write more bytes to the buffer than the configured maximum buffer size: 104857600.'.**

How can I fix it an run with same pipe architecture using **Get File Contetnt**?

[image]

Changed in Settings->Configurations value for this parameteres 300mb:

- Runtime.Backend.HttpOperation.MaxContentSize
- Runtime.ContentLink.MaximumContentSizeInBytes
- Runtime.FlowRunActionJob.MaximumActionResultSize
- Runtime.FlowRunRetryableActionJobCallback.MaximumContentLengthInBytesForPartialContent

Comment: The SharePoint connector is an Azure managed connector. It’s bound by the same constraints as consumption. Have you tried obtaining the content via the Graph API and the HTTP connector? The HTTP connector is in-app. That’s your best bet. Failing that, ADF is your only real hope if you want to use low code tools.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Logic App - read big file (200mb+) from sharepoint via "Get File Contetnt"

Thanks to `@Skin` for suggesting the same point.

You can use `Graph API and the HTTP connector` within a `Logic App` to download a `200MB` file from `Share Point`.

Below are the steps in `Logic App`

**Step 1**: Initially generate access token using below http request.

**`Design:`**

[image]

**Content Type:**

```
Content-Type:

application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

**Body:**

```
grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<app_ID>&client_secret=S968Qrg8fhgjgvnpaap4&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Step 2:**

Get the authorization from previous step by using below method.

Use the below query to get the **Share Point Site ID**

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root:/sites/<sitename>
```

[image]

**Step 3:**

Use the below query to get the **Share Point Drive ID**

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/@{split(body('HTTP_2')['id'],',')[1]}/drives
```

[image]

**Step 4:**

You can use below query to download the files from `Share Point Site` by retrieving parameters by using above responses.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/@{split(body('HTTP_2')['id'],',')[1]}/drives/@{body('HTTP_3')['value'][0]['id']}/root/children/200MB.bin
```

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

AFAIK, If you want to download files that are larger than 100Mb from a `SharePoint` site, this is the only method you can use.